# PuTTY SSH Problem No Such File or Directory

Tags: python, ssh

I'm very much new to using both a terminal and a Raspberry Pi. I'm using a Raspberry Pi Zero (non W version) and I've connected to it using SSH over USB (using PuTTY) and I'm having problems just navigating around. I have a set of 12 folders in my home directory but I can only access one of them, python_games.

[image: Raspberry Pi Folders]

There are the 10 original folders and two I have created, Python and RPi. When i try to change directory using `cd python` I get the error:

[image: Error Message]

Now I don't really know what I have done wrong but please if anyone can help it would be gratefully appreciated!

Thanks, Fred.

Comment: LInux is a real operating system, so it is case sensitive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you are missing an uppercase, at least on the sample command you gave.
Try :

```
cd Python
```

And tell us what is happening :)

I could bet that the only folder you accessed was "python_game", the only one in lowercase !

Comment: Thank you Technico.top! I could have swore I attempted a capital P for Python! Works perfectly!